Infinitely many projective plane conics pass through 4 points.
In general, a projective conic in $\mathbb{P}^2_{[x:y:z]}$ takes the form $$Q:=ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + dxy + exz+fyz.$$ Heuristically, I see that there are 6 degrees of freedom, (the coefficients $a,...,f$) but since two projective conics $Q_1,Q_2$are equal if there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda Q_1 = Q_2$ we are brought down to 5 degrees of freedom. Then, each of the 4 points remove 1 degree of freedom, leaving us with one degree of freedom left to play with which gives us an infinite family of conics.
How do I formulate this in a rigorous manner? I am assuming that I should be able to do this with some basic linear algebra, e.g. some matrix does not have maximal rank.

Well, given a fixed point, what is the condition that a conic passes through that point in terms of the coefficients?

Keyword : (linear) pencil of conics.

@KReiser I am not sure

Well, sounds like you might want to do an example! What's the condition on the coefficients for a conic to pass through $[0:0:1]$? $[0:1:1]$? $[1:1:1]$? $[p:q:r]$?

You suppose that a conic passes through a projective frame $(A,B,C,G)$ with center $G$: $$A=1:0:0,\, B=0:1:0,\,C=0:0:1,\,G=1:1:1$$
Translating this with the coordinates, you obtain that $\exists k \in \mathbb R,$ $$Q: 1(yz-xz)+k(xy-xz)=0$$You obtain a pencil of conics. https://www.geogebra.org/classic/zfbcdupr
